# Make jQuery strings load gettext

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have the following JavaScript (jQuery) snippet of code to load the flex slider in a WordPress theme and to add "prev" and "next" strings:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   // FLEXSLIDER
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
     jQuery('.flexslider<?php echo $post_id; ?>').flexslider({
       controlNav: false,
       slideshow: false,
       prevText: "Prev", // String: Set the text for the "previous" directionNav item
       nextText: "Next",  
       controlsContainer: ".home-navigation<?php echo $post_id; ?>"
     });
   });                  
 </script>
```

The thing is that I want these strings to be loaded from my gettext .mo file so that it loads in German or English when appropriate. I tried by adding:

```
prevText: "<?php echo gettext("Prev"); ?>"
```

as it is a php file, but it did not work somehow. Could be a quotes issue or something else. Not sure yet.

How can I load gettext data instead of these static strings?

Comment: Try `prevText: '<?php echo gettext("Prev"); ?>'`

Comment: This does work as in there are no errors. But the Dutch version for Prev is not loaded even though it is in the mo. If I use something like `nextText: "<?php _e('Next', tk_theme_name); ?>",` and scan the files it using the Localization plugin does find this string and add it, but it is not translated either.

Comment: Is `tk_theme_name` valid?

Comment: If I use `_e` according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e it should be the text domain. When I use `nextText: "<?php _e('Next', child_theme_cosily); ?>",  ` as my child theme is indicated like that in functions.php it still does not seem to load. Could be that my functions.php code is not ok yet: http://pastebin.com/UasipZ4V . Will read some more.

Comment: Somehow I needed to add the text domain for the child theme where I wanted the translation to load as the parent theme was overriding the translations and I think because some of the gettext strings were adjusted by another dev. Now all loads well. So @ElliottFrisch was right. Echoing gettext as suggested before by him and Sibiraj and another post I read somewhere did not work however. Perhaps because the textdomain is needed?

Comment: No. When using [_e](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) the `$domain` **is** optional. But you need a value `default`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a question of loading the proper text domain. Was working with one for child theme and parent theme. Once I adjusted some text domains and turned them into child theme text domains the changed gettext data was properly loaded. I made changes, which were not shown because the parent theme text domain loaded the old data while I added new data to the child theme .mos. All OK now. Thanks @Elliott for his help earlier on!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 // FLEXSLIDER
 jQuery(window).load(function() {
   jQuery('.flexslider<?php echo $post_id; ?>').flexslider({
     controlNav: false,
     slideshow: false,
     prevText: '<?php echo gettext("Prev"); ?>',
     nextText: "Next",  
     controlsContainer: ".home-navigation<?php echo $post_id; ?>"
   });
 });                  
</script>
```